# WIX :: How to install file in LocalLow folder

Tags: windows, wix

Is there way to install file in LocalLow folder using WIX script?

Updated:

I can put the following code for XP

```
<Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
   <Directory Id="ApplicationData">
       <Directory Id="ProductName">
```

and this for Windows Vista and later

```
<Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
   <Directory Id="AppData">
       <Directory Id="LocalLow">
           <Directory Id="ProductName">
```

but how can I push WIX/MSI to select right variant during runtime?

Comment: Not sure I this question voted down, but the documentation contains only information for Local and Roaming folders of AppData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install (copy) files in any folder you have write access to. Just specify the required directory path with Directory elements.

PS: WIX documentation is poor, but don't expect they will list every possible folder on your machine =).

Comment: but LocalLow name is "~\AppData\LocalLow" on W7/W8 and Vista and "~\Application Data\ for XP and I didn't know how to separate them in WIX script

Comment: Just use standard Windows Installer property 'AppDataFolder' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367565%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Answer for edited question: I'd add same component (copy-paste and don't forget to change GUIDs, or invent something more flexible) in both directories and specify different conditions for that components so that one would be installed only on XP and another only on Vista. Example: <Condition>VersionNT>=502</Condition>. More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

AppDataFolder mapped to Roaming folder, so it isn't a solution

1. create a folder like LOCALLOW (parentDir: TARGETDIR)
2. remap it with CustomAction to [%USERPROFILE]\Appdata\LocalLow *(e.g. @WiX CustomAction Id="SET_LocalLowFolder" Directory="LOCALLOWDIR" Value="[%USERPROFILE]\Appdata\LocalLow")* before InstallInitialize.

!!! this folder makes sense only on Vista & later, so make such component conditional